# What shape is traced out by this animation?

Tags: geometry

Found this animation circulating online, and was wondering what shape the rod's end traces out. It seems to be an ellipse, but can that be proved somehow?

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ $[image]

Comment: I would start with "The sum of the distances from the foci to any point on the ellipse is a constant." and then go the trig route.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This is _one_ [source](http://mytechnologyworld9.blogspot.nl/2010/08/complicated-mechanisms-explained-in.html). Nice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the two pivots moving on a cross $a$ and $b$. $a$ moves on $\{(0,t)|t\in[0,1]\}$, and $b$ on $\{(s,0)|t\in[0,1]\}$. Their position must furthermore satisfy
$$s^2+t^2=1$$
The drawing point is positioned at
$$a(t) + (1+l)(b(s)-a(t)) =$$
$$= ((1+l)\sqrt{1-t^2},t+(1+l)t)$$
By parametrizing $t = \cos(\phi)$ we obtain the position
$$((1+l)\sin(\phi),(2+l)\cos(\phi))$$
which is indeed an ellipse when we let $\phi$ run from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Sorry if my solution is a bit messy, but I worked it up while writing it.